# JavaScript - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, a-star

I'm using a [A* pathfinding script](http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/astar-search-algorithm-in-javascript) in a simple JavaScript 2D (canvas) game. I broke my game down to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Anyway, my game is 15 columns across and 10 rows down.

The problem is the error I get. Below I have a way to start and end a path between nodes. Here is the error message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined` on `line 15`. Line 15 is `nodes[x][y] = new GraphNode(x, y, row[x]);` between the second `for` loop.

Here is my `SSCCE`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='graphstar.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var board;
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='astar.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
{
        // UP to DOWN - 10 Tiles (Y)
        // LEFT to RIGHT - 15 Tiles (X)
        graph = new Graph([
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
        [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 1, 1, 13, 1, 1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        ]);
        //Let's do an example test.
        start = graph.nodes[1][2]; // X: 1, Y: 2
        end = graph.nodes[12][7]; // X: 12, Y: 7
        result = astar.search(graph.nodes, start, end);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
Loading... pathfinding. Look in Chrome Console/Firefox Firebug for more information.
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, my game is `jQuery`. Also there is `graphstar.js` and `astar.js`. Don't worry about `astar.js` because it works fine. `graphstar.js` is the where my problem is. `astar.js` is where the `nodes` and such are laid out. `graphstar.js` is where the map is graphed.

See the whole `graphstar.js` here: http://pastebin.com/5AYRreip (Here is `astar.js`: http://pastebin.com/ee6PMzc3)

This is where it's laid out in `graphstar.js`:

```
function Graph(grid) {
    var nodes = [];
    var row, rowLength, len = grid.length;
    for (y = 0; y <= 15; y++) {
        row = grid[y];
        nodes[y] = new Array(15);
        for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
            nodes[x][y] = new GraphNode(x, y, row[x]);
        }
    }
    this.input = grid;
    this.nodes = nodes;
}
```

So, as you can see... `Y` can be `10` or lower. `X` can be `15` or lower. However, I am getting this error.

Where as I am inputting `end = graph.nodes[12][7]; // X: 12, Y: 7`
SHOULD work because it is within the `X` and `Y` bounds... However I am having trouble even setting it up in the first place.

Why is it undefined?

**UPDATE NEW**

```
for (y = 0; y <= 10; y++) {

    row = grid[y];
    nodes[y] = new Array(15);

    for (x = 0; x <= 15; x++) {

        console.log("X: " + x + " Y: " + y);
        //console.log("Row: " + row[x]);
        nodes[x][y] = new GraphNode(x, y, row[x]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting your axes mixed up.

```
function Graph(grid) {
    var nodes = [];
    var row, rowLength, len = grid.length;
    for (y = 0; y <= 15; y++) {
        row = grid[y];
        // Here, you're indexing into `nodes` using `y`, so you're creating
        // an array at `nodes[0]` through `nodes[15]`
        nodes[y] = new Array(15);
        for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
            // But here you're index into `nodes` using `x` in the first dimension,
            // so you're filling in `nodes[0][0]` through `nodes[10][15]`, not
            // `nodes[15][10]`.
            nodes[x][y] = new GraphNode(x, y, row[x]);
        }
    }
    this.input = grid;
    this.nodes = nodes;
}
```

Consequently, when you retrieve `nodes[12]`, you get `undefined` because there's never been a value assigned to that index. Then you try to index into it, and get the error.

You need to make sure you're consistently indexing into the outer array with one coordinate (`x` or `y`, whichever you prefer), and indexing into the inner arrays with the other coordinate (`y` or `x`, whichever you prefer).

Comment: I see. My problem is that if I try to index 15 columns of `Y` and 10 rows of `X`... I get that error.

Comment: @weka: Good deal, glad that helped.

Comment: Yes, I see the problem. Still currently trying to fix it.

Comment: My constructor has 10 rows down... how will I make it 15? I mean how do I expand the elements without expanding the rows?

Comment: @weka: I can't tell you how to fix it because I don't know what you want to achieve; it's up to you to fix it. I can only tell you what's wrong. What you're passing into `Graph` is an 11x16 grid. Within `Graph`, `grid.length` is 11 and `grid[n].length` is 16 (consistently; in JavaScript, it need not be consistent, but in your case it is). But half the time, you're treating it as though it were 16x11 rather than 11x16. You need to be consistent. What form that consistency takes is up to you.

Comment: I want it so I can have my X up to 15 and Y up to 10. Trying to change the numbers around and I get the same error.

Comment: I edited my answer with new format. It's still giving me the error. Cannot set 0 of undefined.